# Making CSV from PHP - Carriage return won't work

Tags: php, csv, carriage-return

Seems like a fairly simple issue but can't get it to work. I am getting the user to download a csv file(which works fine).

Basically I can't get the carriage return to work.

```
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=search_results.csv");
echo '"Name","Age"\n"Chuck Norris","70"';
exit;
```

**Result :** Name     Age\n"Chuck Norris"    70

Tried :

```
echo '"Name","Age",\n,"Chuck Norris","70"';
```

**Result :** Name     Age    \n    Chuck Norris    70
And

```
echo '"Name","Age",\n\r,"Chuck Norris","70"';
```

**Result :** Name     Age    \n\r    Chuck Norris    70

Know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding CSV, see the answer by Brenton. As for the "why it didn't work" answer:

Yup, /n and similar only work in double-quotes :)

e.g.

```
echo '"Name","Age"' . "\n" . '"Chuck Norris","70"';
```

or (this is gonna look awful)

```
echo "\"Name\",\"Age\"\n\"Chuck norris\",\"79\"";
```

but for readability sake:

```
 $nl = "\n";
   echo '"Name","Age"' . $nl .  '"Chuck Norris","70"';
```

Comment: worked! :) had to tweak it a little though --  
echo "\"Name\",\"Age\"\n\"Chuck norris\",\"79\"";

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, probably more robust solution. PHP has a built in function (doesn't it always). [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will write a correctly escaped csv line to a stream, if you're trying to output to the browser, you can use the standard output (stdout) stream instead of a file pointer.

eg.

```
$list = array (
  array('Name', 'Age'),
  array('Chuck Norris', 79)
);

foreach ($list as $line) {
    fputcsv(STDOUT, $line);
}
```

Comment: it also neatly and quietly deals with escaping of things like " in string values, and also automatically adds " around string sequences when you have whitespace, etc, in there.

much better to use the library than reinvent the wheel